# What is the job of autogen.sh when building a c++ package on Linux

Tags: c++, c, makefile, configure

I saw a common pattern when installing a c/c++ package from source on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04):

1. ./autogen.sh
2. ./configure
3. make
4. make install

I understand `make` and `make install`, and I guess `configure` creates a Makefile based on user preferences, but I don't see why `autogen.sh` is necessary.

Does anyone know what it is there for?

Comment: I believe it is needed for autotools/automake.

Comment: a package means what package?

Comment: oh right. sorry. didn't see that in search...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The steps:

1. The `autogen.sh` script generates the `configure` script (from `configure.ac`, using autoconf) and any files it needs (like creating `Makefile.in` from `Makefile.am` using automake). This requires autotools to be installed on your system, and it must be run when checking out the project from source control (if `configure` isn’t checked in). People who download source tarballs can usually skip this step, because output of this step is included in source tarballs.

   **Note** This is usually equivalent to `autoreconf --install`. If there is not `autogen.sh` file, then just run `autoreconf --install` instead. If you have inherited a project with an `autogen.sh`, consider deleting it if you can use `autoreconf --install`.
2. The `configure` script generates `Makefile` and other files needed to build. Typically `Makefile.in` is used as a template to generate `Makefile` (and `config.h.in` to generate `config.h`). This process happens using only standard tools installed on your system, like sed and awk, and doesn't require autotools to be installed.
3. The `make` command builds the software.
4. The `make install` command installs it.

These are broken into different steps because they are often run at different times. The `autogen.sh` step is traditionally run by people who are developing the software, since they are expected to install autoconf on their systems and they make changes to `configure.ac`. End-users are not expected to have autotools installed.

These expectations have been changed a bit now that end-users are more likely to check a project out of source control instead of downloading source releases.

Comment: `autogen.sh` is usually just a wrapper over `autoreconf -i`. Sometimes it's a wrapper around the tools that autoreconf itself calls. It's basically worthless.

Comment: @BlakBat: Added.

Answer (score 9):

This applies only to programs / libraries, which are built using the autotools build chain. It generates the files, which are configured by the `configure` script. The configure script then populates `.in` files and generates `Makefile`s from `Makefile.am` templates. Which can finally be used to compile, link and install the program / library.

It's becoming slowly obsolete with the move to multi platform packages. CMake and more modern tool chains are state of the art.